# Basic bash script arguments

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I'm new to bash script and wanted to know how to do the following. Basically I have the following line

```
./application [channels] -> [message]
```

where I would like to store these into 2 bash variables with the '->' as the delimiter.

ie:

$channels = channels
$message = message

Furthermore, there can be multiple channels separated by a `,` and/or a space. So the full line would be something like this:

./application Channel1, Channel2,Channel3 -> This is a message.

Now in bash, I would like the channels stored in a channels array separated by `,` (and get rid of the space if its there) and message stored in a message variable. The only thing I can put together at the moment is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i
    do
        echo $i
    done
```

can someone help me out?

Comment: You can't use `->` as part of the command line (unless you quote it or escape the `>`), because bash will interpret the `> message` part as an output redirection and never pass it to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're likely to have spaces in your message, keep your arguments in quotes, and you keep it simple:

```
for CHANNEL in $(echo $1 | tr " ," "\n")
do
  echo Channel: ${CHANNEL}
done

echo Message: ${2}
```

Example:

```
anew@buddha:~/dev/so$ bash example.sh "channel1 channel2 channel3" "this is the message"
Channel: channel1
Channel: channel2
Channel: channel3
Message: this is the message
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the answer.
Is there a way to do a usage check so that it only accepts this command if its in the format   
example.sh "<channels>" "<message>"         - ie it needs the " " and also channels are separarated by a space..

Comment: and also - what if the user has a comment which includes ""'' characters.. won't it break the code.. ie
bash example.sh "channel1 channel2" "that's your comment"

Comment: You can escape quotes with `\"` so, with the arguments `"channela channelb channelc" "this is a \"message\""` for the second argument you'll see `Message: this is a "message"`